# Joomla virtuemart top menu missing from backend

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 2.5 and using the virtuemart component version 2.0.20b . The topmenu for the virtuemart component which has the buttons New,Edit,Publish,Unpublish,Archive,Checkin,Trash,Options,Help is missing. Can someone please tell me how to bring that menu back as i have to set permission from the options button in that menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a menu on the front end... Just a hunch, but check your global configuration to see what the default user level is for modules. If it is set to guest, you will only see it one time if you are logged in ad admin or another user because it is not visible to registered users.

If this problem is in the backend, you probably need to repair your database to get it to come back. You will need to go into your hosting control panel to do this.